# How to get distinct values applying an azure table storage query?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, distinct-values

I want to get the "ReceiverEmail" values of a certain PartitionKey "emailAddress".
I want to retrieve only the distinct values of the ReceiverEmail. I am applying this python query on an azure storage table as follows:

```
entit = table_service.query_entities('UserRequests','PartitionKey eq \'' + emailAddress + '\'',select= 'ReceiverEmail')
```

Any help of how to get distinct values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to directly query distinct values. This official document states the operations that are not supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service#unsupported-query-operators

[image]

If you want this feature, you can go to the `feedback website` to post your suggestions, and the Azure development team may adopt your suggestions:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? :( Should I use azure cosmos db sql table to do what I need? @Frank Gong

Comment: As far as I know, `cosmos db` supports `distinct`, you can choose according to your needs.